# Play Framework - Uploading Any File Type

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm have a lot of trouble trying to get this started. I'm using this documentation as a starting point: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaFileUpload

But I want my site to allow the user to upload any kind of files (eg PDF, XML, jpg, excel). Thus I'm confused on how to handle the code in the documentation `FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");`

How do I specify the code `getFile("...")` to retrieve the file as anything?

Comment: Ooooh. I think I might have read that code too literally. Is it because "picture" refers to the name of the input tag?

Comment: Yes, `picture` is just the input name;